# COAUTHIDENTITY with CoSetProxyBlanket using JNA

Tags: java, wmi, jna

I am trying to write a Java API which uses JNA to communicate with WMI with remote machine (provided username and password). 
For this I want to create `COAUTHIDENTITY` object and use it with `CoSetProxyBlanket` in Java. 
The code I am trying to port is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/example--getting-wmi-data-from-a-remote-computer).
Any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map the [COAUTHIDENTITY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wtypesbase/ns-wtypesbase-_coauthidentity) structure in an interface class.  It looks like `WTypesBase` which extends `WTypes` may be a good class name although you can put it anywhere.

The type mappings are simple: what you see as `unsigned long` can be `NativeLong` but since this is Windows-only code you can use `int` as we know it's 32-bit.  The `unsigned short *` pointers are character arrays of 2-byte (wide) characters.  Just use a `Pointer` for those.

So your structure heading should be:

```
class COAUTHIDENTITY extends Structure {
  public Pointer User;
  public int UserLength;
  public Pointer Domain;
  public int DomainLength;
  public Pointer Password;
  public int PasswordLength;
  public int Flags;
}
```

(Field order mappings are left as an exercise for the reader.)

Then to create it:

```
COAUTHIDENTITY auth = new COAUTHIDENTITY();

String user = "username"; // or get from the user
// Allocate memory for user including null terminator
auth.User = new Memory(Native.WCHAR_SIZE * (user.length() + 1));
// Set the widestring in memory
auth.User.setWideString(0, user);
auth.UserLength = user.length();

// Do the same for domain and password

auth.Flags = SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY_ANSI;
// Note: SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY_ANSI = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am facing problem in the immediate next step in setting value to argument `pServerPrincName` for `CoSetProxyBlanket` API. Kindly refer [here](https://pastebin.com/ZSuiSciV) for the code snippet I am using.
I tried using null, empty string as values for that argument. The value for that arguments is `COLE_DEFAULT_PRINCIPAL` which is of type OLECHAR.
@Daniel

Comment: I am faced with error code 0x80070057 denoting I have provided wrong value as argument(s) for that API

Comment: You've correctly used `LPOLESTR` for that type, but it looks from the docs that you might want the Windows constant `COLE_DEFAULT_PRINCIPAL`. That's defined [here](https://github.com/tpn/winsdk-10/blob/master/Include/10.0.10240.0/um/ObjIdl.h) as a pointer to -1... which I'm not sure we can do with the `LPOLESTR` type.  This is probably worthy of a new thread here, or a question on the JNA mailing list.  You might try using a `Pointer` for that variable and manually setting its `peer` value to `-1`.  (No idea if that will work but it's worth a shot!)

Comment: Try this (totally untested, may crash your machine so save first):  `Pointer p = new Pointer();` `Pointer.nativeValue(p, -1);` `LPOLESTR COLE_DEFAULT_PRINCIPAL = new LPOLESTR(p);` and then use that constant in the `CoSetProxyBlanket` call.    I repeat, totally untested and may cause a crash! :)

Comment: `Pointer pAuth = new Pointer(-1); Pointer.nativeValue(pAuth, -1); LPOLESTR COLE_DEFAULT_PRINCIPAL = new LPOLESTR(pAuth);` <BR>
`hres = Ole32.INSTANCE.CoSetProxyBlanket(pSvc.getValue(), Ole32.RPC_C_AUTHN_DEFAULT, Ole32.RPC_C_AUTHZ_DEFAULT, COLE_DEFAULT_PRINCIPAL, Ole32.RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_PRIVACY, Ole32.RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, auth.getPointer(), Ole32.EOAC_NONE);` I used this following code snippet, but I am still getting that same error.

Comment: Code can be found in the same link.

Comment: Don't use `getPointer()` on `auth`. Just pass the structure directly.   I also see you trying to replace `int` with `DWORD`. That doesn't make a difference on the windows side, it's all 32-bit integers.

Comment: Thanks. The suggestion you provided works. But in the next step, when trying to execute the WMI query, I am getting the error code 0x80070005 saying access denied. I am able to execute WMI query through powershell with same user credentials. (Code update in the same url)

Comment: Not sure the empty domain is allowed. In any case, you've gone far afield of this question and it's harder to answer in chat.  Perhaps post your code in a new question showing how far you have got and see if others can advise -- you'll get more response on a new question.  You're past the JNA modeling part and into WMI/COM credentials now and that's a different category of question.

Comment: As per you suggestion I have raised it as a separate clarification [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51941549/issue-when-executing-iwbemservices-execquery-when-executing-wmi-using-jna).
Thanks